# hibernate bidirectional one-to-many inserts duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many, inverse

I'm having issues with a parent-child relationship here.  When I persist from the collection side (child side) I get 2 new children instead of one.

Here is are the hibernate mappings:

```
    <set name="children" inverse="true"
        cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="true"
        order-by="CHILD_ID desc">
        <key column="PARENT_ID" />
        <one-to-many class="com.mycompany.Child" />
    </set>
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="com.mycompany.Parent" not-null="true">
        <column name="PARENT_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Here is the java code used to add the child into the bidirectional relationship:

```
// Persist logic...
Parent p = myParentService.findById(1);
Child c = new Child();
p.addChild(c);
myChildService.persist(child);

// Inside the parent class...
public void addChild(Child child)
{
    if (this.children == null)
        this.children = new LinkedHashSet<Child>();

    this.children.add(child);
    child.setParent(this);
}
```

If I remove the "this.children.add(child);" part everything works as expected.  This is confusing because the Hibernate documentaion [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-bidir) says that bidirectional relationships are supposed to work this way.  What am I missing?

Comment: is setParent also adding the child?

Comment: Nope, setParent just does a simple assign.

Comment: The way to manage the bi-directional association is correct, you need to set both sides of the link. But what do you mean exactly by *I get 2 new children*? Where? In the database? In the collection? Both? How did you implement `equals`/`hashCode`? Are you using the `id` in your implementation? Can you actually show it?

Comment: Actually I am able to persist when only setting one side of the relationship. 

The duplicates are in the database yes.  I haven't written any equals or hashcode methods on the parent, and the child has an equals only.

Comment: See [4.3. Implementing equals() and hashCode()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) about `Set` and `equals`/`hashCode`. Not sure it's related but you should at least fix your current implementation.

Comment: @caleb-cittadino Let us know what happened, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You turned on cascade persist on the parent's collection, so there is no need to call persist explicitly on the child entity.  If the parent is in the managed state, the new child will be persisted the next time a transaction commits/there is a synchronization.  Cascade is not turned on in the example documentation that you linked.

Comment: Are you saying that the cascade style is causing a duplicate child entry?

Comment: @caleb Enabling cascading shouldn't cause duplicates entries.